# concatenate the texts of various text input fields present in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a paragraph which can have various input fields at random indices. I want the full text in exact order as they were present

```
<p>
blah1
<input type="text" value="INPUT1">
blah2
blah3
<input type="text" value="INPUT2">
<input type="text" value="INPUT3">
</p>
```

output needed: blah1 INPUT1 blah2 blah3 INPUT2 INPUT3

Comment: If all you need is the text then assuming you're using jQuery something like this `$("p").text()` should work, do you mean you need the value of the inputs though?

Comment: using $("p").text() will only give the text of paragraph. I want the text of paragraph + values of input fields in exact order as they are present

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please take a look at below jQuery code.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $( ":input" ).css('display', 'none');
  });
```

Answer given above was for the question that was posted earlier. (Below question was posted earlier).

```
<p>
blah1
<input type="text">INPUT1
blah2
blah3
<input type="text">INPUT2
<input type="text">INPUT3
</p>
```

Question was edited some moments ago.

Please check below code, it gives desired output.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(':input').replaceWith(function(){
   return this.value;
 })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It works, but not for your code. You can fetch any text between tags like p or textarea. It's not possible to merge the Text of p with the value="" attribute of your input fields. You can use textareas to make the effect you want.

Try this out:

```
<p>
blah1
<input type="text" value="textfield 1">
blah2
blah3
<input type="text" value="textfield 2">
<input type="text" value="textfield 3">
<textarea>this is a textarea</textarea>
</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$('p').text()
```

Comment: blah1 blah2 and blah3 are also the words in the paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you don't want to modify the document and don't want to use jQuery...

```
  var output = '';
  var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
  var nodes = p.childNodes;
  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    var node = nodes[i];
    switch (node.nodeType) {
      case Node.TEXT_NODE:
        output += node.nodeValue;
        break;
      case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
        output += node.value;
        break;
    }
  }
  console.log(output);
```